# Python & path parse

Tags: python, file, parsing

I need your help to solve this problem using python.
I have a `.txt` file called `good_files` within which each line is a path that leads to a new file.
In each of these files, there are two columns of data that I will have to unite all together to make the curve fitting.
My ask is how can I do that? The biggest problem for me is to understand how to build the loop in order to read every line of the file `good_file.txt`, open the file of that path and take two columns of data to put them in a new file. Sorry but I am a noob in coding, for now. Thaks for your help, guys <3

Comment: Give an example of how the _good_files.txt_ file looks like. It is difficult to understand the structure of the file with what you just said.

Comment: the structure of good_files.txt is like:

secondolotto_1/Station_1__11/Station_1__11_Summary/Chip_004/S_curve/Ch_3_offset_0_Chip_004.txt
secondolotto_1/Station_1__11/Station_1__11_Summary/Chip_004/S_curve/Ch_4_offset_0_Chip_004.txt
and so on..

Comment: for example the file secondolotto_1/Station_1__11/Station_1__11_Summary/Chip_004/S_curve/Ch_3_offset_0_Chip_004.txt 
looks like

$$\begin{matrix}
210  &   0   &    0 \\
215  &   0   &    0 \\
219  &  3    &    0 \\
222  &  326 &   326 \\
224  &   966  & 966 \\
226  &   1000 &   1001 \\
\end{matrix}$$

I take the first and second columns of each file and merge them into a single file which I will then use to do the fit

Answer (score -1):

Since your file names in the comments are too big to write, I'm taking a small example.

Let's assume that you have a source file (`mysource.txt`) with addresses of other files like this.

```
def.txt
ijk.txt
```

And each address is a text file with data like this:

```
1234 5678
2345 6789
```

You want to store all the data into a `result.txt` file.

Take a look at my sample code.

```
def readFromFile (fileName):
    sourceFile = open (fileName, 'r')
    text = []
    for address in sourceFile.readlines ():
        if '\n' in address: text.append (address [:-1])
        else: text.append (address)
    return text
    sourceFile.close ()

def writeToFile (text):
    resultFile = open ('result.txt', 'w')
    for data in text:
        resultFile.write (data + '\n')
    resultFile.close ()

addresses = read ('mysource.txt')
for address in addresses:
    text = read (address)
    write (text)
```

The `readFromFile ()` function takes a single file address and outputs all the lines in file in a single list which is `addresses`.

Now for each address the for loop implements same `readFromFile ()` function to traverse the inner file data, and writes (using `writeToFile ()` function) in a `result.txt`.

Comment: Why are the functions not orthogonal? Using the same name as the built-in `write` method is not technically a problem, but hardly best practice.

Comment: I just wanted to keep the code easy to understand. Now the naming is fixed. Thanks @tripleee